# Is it possible to avoid CORS errors when using the captureMediaStream API on Vimeo resources?

Tags: vimeo

I'm looking to do some background video syncing for a client and I'm wondering if there's a client side work around to run the captureMediaStream browser API against cross origin content that we own.

This is the error I'm getting: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'captureStream' on 'HTMLMediaElement': Cannot capture from element with cross-origin data

My limitations are that the platform is on Shopify which greatly reduces the flexibility I have in originating either the request or some authentication server side.